# how to delete an Uploaded file from the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

Hi all I have an upload function where users can upload the files and I show the uploaded files in a table before inserting in DB and I give an delete option in the table if user wants delete any uploaded file he dsnt want..I am trying this code but, the files are not getting deleted

this is my file upload code

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(string AttachmentName, BugModel model)
   {           
    BugModel bug = null;
    if (Session["CaptureData"] == null)
    {
        bug = model;
    }
    else
    {
        bug = (BugModel)Session["CaptureData"];
    }
    foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file1 = Request.Files[inputTagName];
        if (file1.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            BugAttachment attachment = new BugAttachment();
            var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".doc", ".xlsx", ".txt", ".jpeg", ".docx" };
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file1.FileName);
            if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                model.ErrorMessage = "{ .doc, .xlsx, .txt, .jpeg }, files are allowed.... ";
            }
            else
            {
                string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(file1.FileName);
                string path = "/Content/UploadedFiles/" + filename;
                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~" + path));
                file1.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                attachment.FileName = "~" + path.ToString();
                attachment.AttachmentName = AttachmentName;
                attachment.AttachmentUrl = attachment.FileName;
                bug.ListFile.Add(attachment);
                model = bug;
            }
            Session["CaptureData"] = model;
        }
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("LoadBug", bug);
}
```

this is my view for showing the uploaded files in a table

```
 <table align="center" class="gridtable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Attachment Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Attachment Url
        </th>
        <th>
        Action 
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% if (Model != null && Model.ListFile != null)
       {  %>
    <% foreach (var Emp in Model.ListFile)
       { %>
    <tr class="Data">
        <td >
            <%:Emp.AttachmentName %>
        </td>
        <td >
            <%: Emp.FileName %>
        </td>
       <td>
      <%-- <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete")%>--%>

        <%:Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { @FileName = Emp.FileName })%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

and this is my delete code

```
  public ActionResult Delete(string FileName)
    {

        char DirSeparator = System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        string FilesPath = ";" + FileName;
        string filenameonly = name + Path.GetFileName(FilesPath);
        string FPath = "Content" + DirSeparator + "UploadedFiles" + DirSeparator + filenameonly;
        // Don't do anything if there is no name
        if (FileName.Length == 0) return View();
        // Set our full path for deleting
        string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator;
        // Check if our file exists
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FPath)))
        {
            // Delete our file
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + FPath));

        }       

        return View("LoadBug", Bug);
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object Bug { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does the file path (i.e. fullName) look correct? It looks like you are viewing it in a View after the operation. Does the IIS_USR have the correct privileges to delete file in that directory?

Comment: yes path is showing correct it is not deleting the file it rising this error

Comment: The view 'eac6a6ee-7a54-407d-b1e0-25048aa653a6Bug.xlsx' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Bug/eac6a6ee-7a54-407d-b1e0-25048aa653a6Bug.xlsx.aspx
~/Views/Bug/eac6a6ee-7a54-407d-b1e0-25048aa653a6Bug.xlsx.ascx
~/Views/Shared/eac6a6ee-7a54-407d-b1e0-25048aa653a6Bug.xlsx.aspx
~/Views/Shared/eac6a6ee-7a54-407d-b1e0-25048aa653a6Bug.xlsx.ascx

Comment: i got one more comment is that   The problem is that I missed setting the fileshare property

Comment: icould u plz help to how to set in fileshare property

Comment: could u plz help to how to set in fileshare property

Comment: That error has nothing to do with deleting the file. It is failing because it cannot find the view associated with that action. You should put that error in your question.

Comment: yes u r right i got the answer thank you for your reply

Comment: Kevin Junghans  sir thank you for ur reply

Comment: yes i got the answer and i had updated my answer above